# OleDB: unable to bind DBTYPE_WSTR parameter - got DB_E_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION error

Tags: delphi, api, oledb, parameter-passing

Here is the context, for an OpenSource library :

- I'm calling OleDB library directly from unmanaged code (Delphi);
- I'm binding parameters by creating an `IAccessor` to a `ICommandText` OleDB instance;
- I've no problem with simple types like `DBTYPE_I8` or `DBTYPE_DATE`;
- I would like to bind textual parameters as `DBTYPE_WSTR` type, i.e. always as Unicode.

**The issue is that for `DBTYPE_WSTR` type, I get an OLEDB Error 80040E1D (DB_E_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION) error, 'Requested conversion is not supported', when `Command.Execute` is called.**

Of course, I've tried with or without `DBTYPE_BYREF` data layout (i.e. setting `FIELDTYPE2OLEDB[ftUTF8]=DBTYPE_WSTR or DBTYPE_BYREF` in code below, and changing the layout): same issue... it works with `DBTYPE_WSTR` but not with `DBTYPE_STR`.

But if I change the parameter type from `DBTYPE_WSTR` into `DBTYPE_STR` (i.e. setting `FIELDTYPE2OLEDB[ftUTF8]=DBTYPE_STR or DBTYPE_BYREF` in code below), the command executes without any problem. But I would like to use `DBTYPE_WSTR` wType instead, to ensure that no character is lost because of the current Ansi Charset.

In fact, I can retrieve any `IRowSet` data without any problem as `DBTYPE_WSTR`, but I can't bound a parameter value with `DBTYPE_WSTR`.

I'm connected to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. The code works with no parameters in the SQL request, or with int or floating-point parameters, but not with TEXT parameters.

Here is the main sample code:

```
Query.Execute('select * from Person.Address where AddressLine1 like ?;',true,['% Drive']);
```

`AddressLine1` column is defined as `nvarchar(60)` in the *AdventureWorks2008R2* reference sample database, so it *should* map with `DBTYPE_WSTR`, according to [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130984.aspx).

The full source code of the corresponding unit is available from [our source code repository](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynOleDB.pas). The code is in the `TOleDBStatement.Execute` method, as such:

```
const
  PARAMTYPE2OLEDB: array[TSQLDBParamInOutType] of DBPARAMIO = (
    DBPARAMIO_INPUT, DBPARAMIO_OUTPUT, DBPARAMIO_INPUT or DBPARAMIO_OUTPUT);
  FIELDTYPE2OLEDB: array[TSQLDBFieldType] of DBTYPE = (
    DBTYPE_EMPTY, DBTYPE_NULL, DBTYPE_I8, DBTYPE_R8, DBTYPE_CY, DBTYPE_DATE,
    DBTYPE_WSTR or DBTYPE_BYREF, DBTYPE_BYTES or DBTYPE_BYREF);

  (...)
  OleDBCheck((fSession as IDBCreateCommand).
    CreateCommand(nil,IID_ICommandText,ICommand(fCommand)));
  fCommand.SetCommandText(DBGUID_DEFAULT,pointer(Utf8DecodeToRawUnicodeUI(aSQL)));
  P := pointer(fParams);
  SetLength(fParamBindings,fParamCount);
  B := pointer(fParamBindings);
  for i := 1 to fParamCount do begin
    B^.iOrdinal := i; // parameter index (starting at 1)
    B^.eParamIO := PARAMTYPE2OLEDB[P^.VInOut]; // parameter direction
    B^.wType := FIELDTYPE2OLEDB[P^.VType];     // parameter data type
    // set additional fields
    case P^.VType of
    ftInt64, ftDouble, ftCurrency, ftDate: begin
      // those types match the VInt64 binary representation :)
      B^.cbMaxLen := sizeof(Int64);
      B^.dwPart := DBPART_VALUE;
      B^.obValue := PAnsiChar(@P^.VInt64)-pointer(fParams);
    end;
    ftUTF8, ftBlob: begin
      // sent as DBTYPE_BYREF mapping directly the VRawByteString content
      B^.dwPart := DBPART_VALUE or DBPART_LENGTH or DBPART_STATUS;
      B^.obValue := PAnsiChar(@P^.VRawByteString)-pointer(fParams);
      B^.cbMaxLen := sizeof(Pointer);
      Len := length(P^.VRawByteString);
      if P^.VType=ftUTF8 then
        Len := Len shr 1; // expect length in WideChar count, excluding #0 
      P^.VInt64 := Len; // store length in unused VInt64 property
      B^.obLength := PAnsiChar(@P^.VInt64)-pointer(fParams);
      B^.obStatus := B^.obLength+4;
    end;
    end;
    inc(P);
    inc(B);
  end;
  OleDBConnection.OleDBCheck((fCommand as IAccessor).CreateAccessor(
    DBACCESSOR_PARAMETERDATA,fParamCount,Pointer(fParamBindings),0,
    fDBParams.HACCESSOR,nil));
 OleDBConnection.OleDBCheck(fCommand.Execute(
    nil,IID_IRowset,fDBParams,nil,@fRowSet),ParamsStatus);
```

My question is therefore:

**How to bind a `B^.wType=DBTYPE_WSTR` parameter for a  `nvarchar()` column without having a DB_E_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION error in `fCommand.Execute`.**

I suspect there is some property to set to the `ISession` or `ICommand` instance, or some flag/option to set, but I was not able to find which one from MSDN documentation. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Why did some "proud anonmous" downvote this question?

Comment: good question. best guess is its hard to tell exactly what you are asking. You jump right in. Give some back ground to what your environment is, what you are trying to do at the begining, and clearly state what you are asking. idk, thats a guess, its not like anyhting jumps out

Comment: I suspect my question is a bit technical. It deals with direct access to OleDB, not high-level access. I highlighted the issue I want to fix by putting it in bold, updated the source code, and asking a direct question in the last paragraph. Hope it's easier to understand.

Comment: I will admit, I hardly skimmed over it, it was long, no clue how to answer it, no idea what you are even talking about, and have never written a line of Delphi ever. I have made offense where I meant none. I am Ashamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK... after some more hours, I think I've found out.

The issue was not in my code AFAIK, but in the Microsoft SQL Server OleDB provider from Microsoft. Using `DBTYPE_WSTR`, as the official documentation states, just doesn't work. I don't say that MS wrote bugs, but I was really [confused by the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130984.aspx), which clearly stated on the same line: `nvarchar DBTYPE_WSTR`.

I've just finally tried with `DBTYPE_BSTR`, using an Ole `WideString`... and it worked as expected!

I just guess that Microsoft and most OleDB consumers just use `DBTYPE_BSTR`.

Here is [some working code](http://synopse.info/fossil/info/d42f1ad819):

```
    ftUTF8: begin
      // mapping directly the WideString VText content
      B^.wType := DBTYPE_BSTR; // DBTYPE_WSTR just doesn't work :(
      B^.obValue := PAnsiChar(@P^.VText)-pointer(fParams);
      B^.cbMaxLen := sizeof(Pointer);
    end;
```

What's fine with `WideString` is that it can be resized by the provider in case of an Output or Input/Output parameter (when callling stored procedures).

Comment: Unit seems now working fine, at least with SQL Server 2008 R2 and Oracle 11g. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/06/27/SynOleDB%3A-OpenSource-Unit-for-direct-access-to-any-database-via-OleDB